# Kotlin - Clarification Needed Regarding the Data Classes Copy Function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, jetpack-compose

Hello everyone I am new to Jetpack Compose.
Needed clarification reagarding the usage of **Copy** Function in kotlin Data Classes.

Here i am using a **NetworkFetchState** abstract class, which helps me determine the state of the network call.

// Abstract Class

```
abstract class NetworkFetchState(
 val isLoading: Boolean = false,
 val isSuccess: Boolean = false,
 val isError: Boolean = false,
 val error: Throwable? = null,
 val errorMessage: String? = null
)
```

I am creating the data class that is extending this abstract class

```
data class LoginDataState(
    val responseData: LoginResponse? = null
) : NetworkFetchState() // extending the Abstract Class
```

Now inside the ViewModel Class i am creating a mutable state flow

```
class MyViewModel:ViewModel(){
 
    // Mutable State Flow of the Data State
    private val _loginDataState = MutableStateFlow(LoginDataState())

    // readonly value of the __loginDataState
    val loginDataState: StateFlow<LoginDataState> get() = _loginDataState

/*
* Here I am performing network calls inside the view model scope
* based on the result from the network call i am trying to update the MutableStateFlow
*/

  fun makeNetworkCall(){
    // ....
    _loginDataState.update { prevState ->
        prevState.copy(
         // ---- PROBLEM HERE ----
         // isLoading, isSuccess.. etc (all other variables from abstract class)
         // are not available
        )
     }
  }

}
```

all the member variables that are extending from abstract class are not visible.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As explained in the answer, the issue has nothing to do with neither Jetpack Compose nor `MutableStateFlow`, it's purely the matter of how data classes work. Maybe you should consider changing the title to avoid confusion and help others to find the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.copy` function is a function generated by kotlin compiler for all data classes. As per the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html), it's using only *properties declared in the primary constructor*.

If you want to change those properties with copy function, you will have to add them to the primary constructor somehow.

```
// this would work
data class LoginDataState(
    val responseData: LoginResponse? = null,
    val _isLoading: Boolean = false,
) : NetworkFetchState(isLoading = _isLoading)

// this is probably better
interface NetworkFetchState {
    val isLoading: Boolean get() = false
}

data class LoginDataState(
    val responseData: LoginResponse? = null,
    override val isLoading: Boolean = false,
) : NetworkFetchState
```